# Webbrowser 'directory not found' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, chromium, python-webbrowser

I am having a reoccurring error with the webbrowser module on python. Whenever I run this program, I get a multiple errors.

```
import webbrowser
google_urls = ["www.gmail.com", "www.youtube.com"]
def open_tabs(url_lists):
    for url in url_lists:
        webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
def main():
    webbrowser.open("www.google.com", new=2, autoraise=False)
    open_tabs(google_urls)

main()
```

These are the errors I get:
/home/garion/Documents/www.youtube.com: No such file or directory (also 2 more, which are the same, except the are for www.google.com and www.gmail.com)

I am using lubuntu, python IDLE 3.5, and Chromium.

Comment: See answer below.  That is the issue

Answer (score 1):

```
webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com')
```

use the https:// in front.